# Issue with creating a dynamic / interactive map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, maps, tidyverse

I've been using the library / package 'brazilmaps' in order to graphically represent the area that has been affected by deforestation in Amazonia.

With the help of the aforementioned library, I've managed to get a visualisation of those Brazilian states that are closer to the river; hence, affected by deforestation the most.

However, what I've set out to do is to trace the evolution of deforestation in these regions from 1988 to 2021.

Unfortunately enough, I have no clue on how to elaborate a dynamic map, one that could highlight (preferably, in colour) what has been the impact in terms of deforestation.

I am kindly asking for your help!

What I have done so far is, as follows:

```
library(sf)
library(patchwork)
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(brazilmaps)

AmazoniaStates <- AmazoniaDeforestation %>% 
dplyr::select(-"Total")


States_Map <- get_brmap(geo = "State",
                 geo.filter = list(State = c(12, 13, 16, 21, 51, 15, 11, 14, 17)),
                 class = "sf")

AmazoniaStateDeforestation <- plot_brmap(States_Map, data_to_join = AmazoniaStates,
join_by = character(), theme = theme_map())

AmazoniaStates <- AmazoniaStates %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = !Year,
           names_to = "State",
           values_to = "Area")
```

And my `dput()` is as follows:

```r
dput(AmazoniaDeforestation)
structure(list(Year = c(1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 
1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), `Acre ` = c(620, 540, 550, 380, 
400, 482, 482, 1208, 433, 358, 536, 441, 547, 419, 883, 1078, 
728, 592, 398, 184, 254, 167, 259, 280, 305, 221, 309, 264, 372, 
257, 444, 682, 706, 889), Amazonas = c(1510, 1180, 520, 980, 
799, 370, 370, 2114, 1023, 589, 670, 720, 612, 634, 885, 1558, 
1232, 775, 788, 610, 604, 405, 595, 502, 523, 583, 500, 712, 
1129, 1001, 1045, 1434, 1512, 2306), Amapa = c(60, 130, 250, 
410, 36, 0, 0, 9, 0, 18, 30, 0, 0, 7, 0, 25, 46, 33, 30, 39, 
100, 70, 53, 66, 27, 23, 31, 25, 17, 24, 24, 32, 24, 17), `Maranhao ` = c(2450, 
1420, 1100, 670, 1135, 372, 372, 1745, 1061, 409, 1012, 1230, 
1065, 958, 1085, 993, 755, 922, 674, 631, 1271, 828, 712, 396, 
269, 403, 257, 209, 258, 265, 253, 237, 336, 350), `Mato Grosso` = c(5140, 
5960, 4020, 2840, 4674, 6220, 6220, 10391, 6543, 5271, 6466, 
6963, 6369, 7703, 7892, 10405, 11814, 7145, 4333, 2678, 3258, 
1049, 871, 1120, 757, 1139, 1075, 1601, 1489, 1561, 1490, 1702, 
1779, 2213), Para = c(6990, 5750, 4890, 3780, 3787, 4284, 4284, 
7845, 6135, 4139, 5829, 5111, 6671, 5237, 7510, 7145, 8870, 5899, 
5659, 5526, 5607, 4281, 3770, 3008, 1741, 2346, 1887, 2153, 2992, 
2433, 2744, 4172, 4899, 5238), `Rondonia ` = c(2340, 1430, 1670, 
1110, 2265, 2595, 2595, 4730, 2432, 1986, 2041, 2358, 2465, 2673, 
3099, 3597, 3858, 3244, 2049, 1611, 1136, 482, 435, 865, 773, 
932, 684, 1030, 1376, 1243, 1316, 1257, 1273, 1673), `Roraima ` = c(290, 
630, 150, 420, 281, 240, 240, 220, 214, 184, 223, 220, 253, 345, 
84, 439, 311, 133, 231, 309, 574, 121, 256, 141, 124, 170, 219, 
156, 202, 132, 195, 590, 297, 315), `Tocantins ` = c(1650, 730, 
580, 440, 409, 333, 333, 797, 320, 273, 576, 216, 244, 189, 212, 
156, 158, 271, 124, 63, 107, 61, 49, 40, 52, 74, 50, 57, 58, 
31, 25, 23, 25, 37), Total = c(21050, 17770, 13730, 11030, 13786, 
14896, 14896, 29059, 18161, 13227, 17383, 17259, 18226, 18165, 
21651, 25396, 27772, 19014, 14286, 11651, 12911, 7464, 7000, 
6418, 4571, 5891, 5012, 6207, 7893, 6947, 7536, 10129, 10851, 
13038)), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help on how I can make this map interactive on a yearly basis would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: hi. generally seems interesting. however, it seems brazilmaps is not actively maintained any longer and there seem to be some issues with later versions of sf. (Your code is not working with current R / sf versions). In general, I'd recommend to have a look at the gganimate package. And update your R. (But then, you might not be able to use brasilmaps any more)

Comment: Hi, @tjebo! Many thanks for your comment! Yes, 'brazilmaps' is indeed somewhat problematic insofar that it is no longer mantained and that it includes a couple of commands only. I am familiar with the 'gganimate' package, thank you, but the thing is that -needless to say- I have to create a static version first before proceeding to make a dynamic / interactive version out of it. Would you, by chance, suggest me some alternative R maps package for me to be able to achieve that? Many thanks indeed in advance!

Comment: maybe check rnaturalearth. it contains to my knowledge one of the most uptodate R maps of our dear planet. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rnaturalearth/vignettes/rnaturalearth.html

Comment: and your question slightly reminded me of another quite a while ago - the thread might help you with your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61399792/gganimatetransition-time-results-in-flying-polygons

Comment: last, but not least, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geobr/vignettes/intro_to_geobr.html might also be useful.  this package is still supported

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible with the {geobr} and {gganimate} packages.

{brazilmaps} is not actively maintained any longer and there seem to be some issues with later versions of sf.

Below should help as a decent start. I guess one can play with the transition objects etc. Some comments in the code.

```r
library(tidyverse) 
library(gganimate)
library(sf)
library(geobr)

deforest_long <- 
  AmazoniaDeforestation %>%
  select(-Total) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "name_state", values_to = "area")
amazon <- read_amazon()

## this is just a rough way to harmonize the region names - might need more work from your side
meso <- read_meso_region() %>%
  mutate(name_state = stringi::stri_trans_general(str = name_state, id = "Latin-ASCII"))

meso_deforest <- left_join(meso, deforest_long, by = "name_state") 

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = meso, color = "darkgrey") +
  geom_sf(data = meso_deforest, aes(fill = area, group = interaction(area, Year)))  +
  ## optional to outline the Amazonian region
  geom_sf(data = amazon, color = "darkred", size = 4, , fill = NA)

anim <- p + transition_time(Year) + labs(title = '{round(frame_time)}')

animate(anim, fps = 2, nframes = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @tjebo, please receive my massive thanks for your highly useful and relevant input! Best regards, A.

Comment: Hello again, @tjebo ! I am really sorry for bothering you, but would you know by chance how to add "viridis" scale to this map? I am relatively new to R, and I've been stuck with this issue for hours, unfortunately to no avail. Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: @ArtUr693 to your plot, just add `+scale_fill_viridis_c()`. that's all :)